# WPF watermark Mahaps with defined style

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I am trying to have watermark on my MahApps.Metro textbox to which I have set a custom style:

```
Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />-->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 30 0" />
            <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SteelBlue" />-->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.7" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                            <Border Background="OrangeRed" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="5"
                                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, 
                                          Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                                <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white" />
                            </Border>

                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MenuLevel2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="SteelBlue"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>



<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtBox_updateWebSrvURL" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"  
                                             Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
                                             Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=webSrvURL,
                                             ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"  
                                             Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="MyWatermark here!!!!/" />
```

If I remove the custom style the watermark is well applied. Any idea how I can enable the watermark but still use my custom style?

Comment: You need to include the watermark in your custom ControlTemplate.

Comment: Can you show Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark code?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />-->
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 30 0" />
                <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SteelBlue" />-->
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.7" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             x:Name="textSource" 
                             Background="Transparent" 
                             Panel.ZIndex="2" />

                            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" x:Name="placeholdertext" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                                <TextBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>                                                    
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="!">
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBox.Style>
                            </TextBox>                                
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>                        
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                                <Border Background="OrangeRed" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                            Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="5"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, 
                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white" />
                                </Border>

                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

TextBox

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtBox_updateWebSrvURL" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"  
                                         Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
                                         Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=webSrvURL,
                                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"  
                                         Tag="MyWatermark here!!!!/" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. It does the job but I see a side effect which is when a field is disabled the watermark is still visible on the top of the existing value. Have you got any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Salim  as i tested this is not happening, if field is disabled watermark gone, but still i updated the codes

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed answer. I do confirm that the watermark still get printed when the field is disabled with a value in it. It is like if the code detect that the value is null when the field is disabled and print the watermark on top of what is present in the field. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: @Salim as i am checking with same, but no watermark get printed https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlsWJhYaBXFre2hlrd-TW9CZQ6M

Comment: Hello, well there should be something that interferes. Any hint on how to debug?